# How can i get the value from a dropdown of div class in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

How can i select a value from the dropdown using selenium web driver
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the drop down is implemented using a `ul` and `li`, so you can't use `WebDriver's Select` class, it will throw `UnexpectedTagNameException` if you do so.

What you need to do in this case, write a custom select method like below to help you.

```
    public void select_by_index(int index){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']")).click();
        WebElement _element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//ul[@role='listbox']//li)[" + index+ "]")); 
        _element.click();
    }
```

So what we are doing here:

- Click the drop down to show all the options, so that they are visible.
- We are dynamically creating xpath for different element in the drop-down list and then clicking on the elements.
- If you pass 2 as argument, it will select 'Change of Mind' from the drop-down and so on.

Try this and let us know if this works in your case. The code is just for illustration purpose.

Comment: The code in your example does not seem to be c# code. However OP asks about c#

Comment: My intention was to give an idea how to solve the problem. The code is written in Java, however the same can be translated to C#. Hope that's not a problem.